# What could I do to speed up this data smoothing function?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, mean

The aim for this function is to smooth the data (based on a 1/3 octave window):

```
def getRollingMean(data, freq, fLim):
    meanData = []
    for fl in fLim:
        meanData.append(np.mean(data[(freq > fl[0]) & (freq < fl[1])]))
    return np.array(meanData)
```

`data` is the data I want to smooth.

`freq` is a frequency axis of the same length as `data`.

`fLim` is a 2 columns array where columns 1 is the lower frequency limit of the 1/3 octave and column 2 is the upper frequency limit.
Each row corresponds to a value of `freq`.

Example:

```py
data = [1,5,3,0]
freq = [100,150,225,337.5]
fLim = [(50, 200),
        (75,300),
        (112 450),
        (168,674)]

# Apply the function to get
mean = [3,3,2.6,3]
```

Unfortunately this function is very slow because I have a big amount of data. The length of the arrays can be for example 720,000!

How could I speed up this function?

Comment: Consider moving to Code Review Stack Exchange, since this works and just requires optimization

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300981/performance-question-stack-overflow-or-code-review → seems OK here

Comment: Could you post some sample data?

Comment: name of function suggests doing something different than you actually do. If I'm wrong, and you really do rolling mean, and data is just some part, a rolling window of the long array, the whole approach should be changed

Comment: @dankai444 I'm not sure what you mean. Data is the whole array, for each point of data, I have a value and the corresponding frequency. What i want to do is average each point of data with every point that are in the same 1/3 octave. The function is working but is really slow because I'm doing a for loop on each point.
I will add an example.

Comment: Google term "rolling mean, moving average". In the example you provided there is no "for loop on each point", there is for loop for each filter (which BTW are not 1/3 octave, they are 2 octave)